# Encrypt a single SQLite table in android and not the entire database

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I have been using SQLite as a database for the android app.
The scenario is I have to create a table called "user_credentials" which will store the username and passwords of the users.

I want to only encrypt that specific table and not the entire Sqlite db.

On the setup of the app, the entered username and password if successful has to be then saved in the user_credentials table with encrypted and when the user logout and login again, it will check the user_credential table and match with the contained values in it.

**

> I want to only encrypt a single sqlite table and not the entire sqlite
>   database!

**

Comment: just encrypt/decrypt the data you are inserting/selecting fromthe database

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [How to encrypt sqlite texts without 3rd party libraries (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254879/how-to-encrypt-sqlite-texts-without-3rd-party-libraries-android/58296548#58296548)

Comment: You should not store the users password in your database, not even in encrypted form. The secure way to implement password validation is by using password hashing algorithms like e.g BCrypt, scrypt or Argon2 that are invented for this.

Comment: SQLCipher 4.3.0 adds the ability to create [Encrypted Virtual Tables](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/encrypted-virtual-tables/) for Commercial packages. This let's you partially encrypt a single table.