# How to encrypt sqlite file using aes algorithm?

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-sqlite, aes

I am trying to encrypt the sql file using aes algorithm. What i have seen in the whole internet is encrypting only the string data or encrypting every data inside the database using sqlite cipher. I want to encrypt every data inside the database using android cryptography with AES algorithm but not adding dependencies like SQLiteCipher. And saving the PassPhrase in the new file in external storage. Can it be done? Help me

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;


import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sqlitepractise.model.Contact;
import com.example.sqlitepractise.params.Params;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;


public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MyDbHandler(Context context){
        super(context, Params.DB_NAME, null, Params.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String create =  "CREATE TABLE " + Params.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + Params.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Params.KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_PHONE + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_SECRET + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_IV + " TEXT" + ")";

        Log.d("practise", "Query being run is : " + create);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            values.put(Params.KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
            values.put(Params.KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone_number());
            db.insert(Params.TABLE_NAME, null,values);
            Log.d("practise", "Successfully inserted");
            db.close();

            // I wanted the encryption to be executed in this method

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    public List<Contact> getAllContact(){

        // I wanted the decryption to be executed in this method        

        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        //Generate the query to read from the database
        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Params.TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, null);

        //Loop Through now
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(2));
                contactList.add(contact);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }

    private static int READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER = 1024;
    private static String ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTOR = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final static String ALGO_SECRET_KEY = "AES";

    public static void encryptFile(String keyStr, String specStr, 
    InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, 
    IOException {
        try{
            IvParameterSpec iv = new 
            IvParameterSpec(specStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new 
            SecretKeySpec(keyStr.getBytes("UTF-8"), ALGO_SECRET_KEY);
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTOR);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,iv);
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER];
            while ((count = in.read(buffer))>0)
                out.write(buffer,0,count);
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am trying to encrypt the sql file using aes algorithm.` A file is a file. Does not matter what the file contains.

Comment: `encrypting only the string data or encrypting every data inside the database ` Well you can do that but then you are not encrypting a file but data in a file. Encrypt the file! Much easier.

Comment: Maybe you should think over your needs - storing data in encrypted form is simple BUT a database is designed to get the stored data back to the user. If you try to find one dataset you need to decrypt each dataset, compare it to your search pattern and so on. Ususally only the sensitive data (columns) need to get encrypted (e.g. Phone Number). On Android it depends on the target sdk-version if you need additional dependencies or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to encrypt every data inside the database ....

1. With your database as it is then that is impossible as the table includes `Params.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"`

- This column will be an alias of the rowid column. A rowid or an alias thereof **MUST** be an integer otherwise an SQLITE_MISIMATCH error will result. So encrypting that column will not work. The value itself if not encrypted would be of little use, it simply uniquely identifies the row.

2. You include the commented code (included below), which indicates that theoretically you want to encrypt according to rows.

:-

```
public void addContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    try {
        values.put(Params.KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(Params.KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone_number());
        db.insert(Params.TABLE_NAME, null,values);
        Log.d("practise", "Successfully inserted");
        db.close();

        // I wanted the encryption to be executed in this method

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

It would be useless to insert a row and to then encrypt unless you are encrypting the database file entirely. So considering point 1 and the apparent wish to encrypt at the row level then you either

1. encrypt the data as a whole and insert into a single row or
2. you individually encrypt each column and then insert the encrypted data.

   1. it makes sense to reduce overheads and only encrypt sensitive columns

**Option 2** would be the least complicated as for option 1 not only would you need the means of encrypting/decrypting but you would additionally need a means of concatenating and splitting the multiple data items.

Your encryption method assumes encrypting a file, the individual rows are not files they are part of the file. Such a method would only suit encrypting the entire database which would require decryption of the entire database file before opening the database into another file and encryption of the entire database into the encrypted file, which has it's own complications.

**Example based upon option 2**

Taking your code and modifying it to be (for demonstration of the principle) :-

then **MyDbHandler** could be :-

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    EncryptDecrypt ed;
    String KEYSTR = "this is my key string";
    String SPECSTR = "this is my specstring";

    public MyDbHandler(Context context){
        super(context, Params.DB_NAME, null, Params.DB_VERSION);
        ed = new EncryptDecrypt();
        EncryptDecrypt.setIvParameterSpec(new
                IvParameterSpec(SPECSTR.substring(0,16).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        EncryptDecrypt.setSecretKeySpec(new
                SecretKeySpec(KEYSTR.substring(0,16).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ALGO_SECRET_KEY));
        try {
            ed.setCipher(Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTOR));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String create =  "CREATE TABLE " + Params.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + Params.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Params.KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_PHONE + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_SECRET + " TEXT, " + Params.KEY_IV + " TEXT" + ")";

        Log.d("practise", "Query being run is : " + create);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            values.put(Params.KEY_NAME,ed.encrypt(contact.getName()));
            values.put(Params.KEY_PHONE,ed.encrypt(contact.getPhone_number()));
            db.insert(Params.TABLE_NAME, null,values);
            Log.d("practise", "Successfully inserted");
            db.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        //Generate the query to read from the database
        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Params.TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, null);

        //Loop Through now
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Params.KEY_ID)));
                contact.setName(ed.decrypt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Params.KEY_NAME))));
                contact.setPhone_number(ed.decrypt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Params.KEY_PHONE))));
                contactList.add(contact);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close(); //<<<< SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE CURSORS
        return contactList;
    }

    private static int READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER = 1024;
    private static String ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTOR = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final static String ALGO_SECRET_KEY = "AES";

    /*

    public static void encryptFile(String keyStr, String specStr,
                                   InputStream in, OutputStream out)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            IOException {
        try{
            IvParameterSpec iv = new
                    IvParameterSpec(specStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new
                    SecretKeySpec(keyStr.getBytes("UTF-8"), ALGO_SECRET_KEY);
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_FILE_ENCRYPTOR);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,iv);
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER];
            while ((count = in.read(buffer))>0)
                out.write(buffer,0,count);
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

     */
}
```

and the supportive **EncryptDecrypt** class as :-

```
class EncryptDecrypt {
    private Cipher cipher;
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private static IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;


    /**
     *
     * @Param toEncrypt     The string to be encrypted
     * @return              The encrypted data as a string
     */
    String encrypt(String toEncrypt) {
        byte[] encrypted;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec,ivParameterSpec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt an encrypted string
     * @param toDecrypt     The encrypted string to be decrypted
     * @return              The decrypted string
     */
    String decrypt(String toDecrypt)  {
        byte[] decrypted;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec,ivParameterSpec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(toDecrypt,Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return new String(decrypted);
    }

    public void setCipher(Cipher cipher) {
        this.cipher = cipher;
    }

    public static IvParameterSpec getIvParameterSpec() {
        return ivParameterSpec;
    }

    public static void setIvParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec) {
        EncryptDecrypt.ivParameterSpec = ivParameterSpec;
    }

    public static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec() {
        return secretKeySpec;
    }

    public static void setSecretKeySpec(SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec) {
        EncryptDecrypt.secretKeySpec = secretKeySpec;
    }
}
```

and to demonstrate **MainActivity** as :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyDbHandler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new MyDbHandler(this);

        db.addContact(new Contact(0,"Fred Bloggs","1111111111"));
        db.addContact(new Contact(0,"Jane Doe","2222222222"));
        db.addContact(new Contact(0,"Miss Scarlet","3333333333"));

        Cursor csr = db.getWritableDatabase().query(Params.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,"(random())");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();

        for(Contact c : db.getAllContact()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Name is " + c.getName() + " Phone is " + c.getPhone_number());
        }

    }
}
```

The output to the Log would be (when run as a new install) :-

```
2021-12-21 09:54:30.083 D/practise: Query being run is : CREATE TABLE mytable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,_name TEXT, _phone TEXT, _secret TEXT, _iv TEXT)
2021-12-21 09:54:30.086 D/practise: Successfully inserted
2021-12-21 09:54:30.100 I/chatty: uid=10164(a.a.so70410018javasqliteencryptdb) identical 1 line
2021-12-21 09:54:30.113 D/practise: Successfully inserted

2021-12-21 09:54:30.121 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ec73c85
2021-12-21 09:54:30.121 I/System.out: 0 {
2021-12-21 09:54:30.121 I/System.out:    _id=2
2021-12-21 09:54:30.121 I/System.out:    _name=at3jvwWB4LcYZHFWcdVhbw==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.121 I/System.out:    _phone=qqypV3kzmDrj6MruN1npvA==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _secret=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _iv=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: }
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: 1 {
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _id=3
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _name=DLeinhF4EoxeNZCRUZyOFw==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _phone=V1ZkbeIPV3Rqm6Uajc93Sg==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _secret=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _iv=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: }
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: 2 {
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _id=1
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _name=lRGUesUDAZegVCgfIKVDIg==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _phone=Q/CNAvw/xV1+LzWWSw8SKg==
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _secret=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out:    _iv=null
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: }
2021-12-21 09:54:30.122 I/System.out: <<<<<

2021-12-21 09:54:30.127 D/DBINFO: Name is Fred Bloggs Phone is 1111111111
2021-12-21 09:54:30.127 D/DBINFO: Name is Jane Doe Phone is 2222222222
2021-12-21 09:54:30.127 D/DBINFO: Name is Miss Scarlet Phone is 3333333333
```

Using App Inspection to look at the database shows :-

[image]

The above code is based upon the following more comprehensive answers that you may wish to consider:-

[Encrypt data in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508440/encrypt-data-in-sqlite/47518804#47518804)

and

[How to encrypt sqlite texts without 3rd party libraries (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254879/how-to-encrypt-sqlite-texts-without-3rd-party-libraries-android/58263685#58263685)