# Can sqlite3 only encrypt the table structure without encrypting the data content?

Tags: c++, sqlite, encryption, c++20

I have developed a client software that needs to use sqlite3 to store data. It will store some data on the user's computer that needs to be encrypted.

I manually encrypt the data using RSA before storing it in the database (when I need a lookup, I do the lookup directly using the encrypted data). But when multiple cells have the same data, their encrypted data is also the same, so when the database file is leaked, the attacker may analyze the data characteristics. So can sqlite3 only encrypt the table structure without encrypting the data content?

Language: C++20, Platform: Windows/Linux/Android

Comment: Another reason why I only need to encrypt the table structure and not the data is that I might have some data that doesn't need to be encrypted and data that needs to be encrypted stored in the same table.

Comment: *...but when multiple cells have the same data, their encrypted data is also the same...* Not if you're using the appropriate encryption scheme.

Comment: If your language is c++20, why did you use the c tag?

Comment: But if the encrypted data is different, all data must be decrypted to be retrieved, and indexing cannot be used for fast retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite relies heavily upon the schema aka **`sqlite_master`** (the table structure, along with other components such as indexes, views and triggers). If solely this were encrypted then there is little doubt that issues (exceptions) would ensue.

When using the likes of SQLCipher, this is not an issue as the entire file is encrypted/decrypted as one.

To do what you wish would very likely involve writing a customised version of SQLite from custom source code. Perhaps refer to https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html.

I guess an alternative would be to ascertain and encrypt/decrypt the pages that sqlite_master uses, but that would still likely require handling the file before/after access the file via the SQLite API. Of course the other/actual data would be no different (not encrypted) and potentially hackable from the file.

If you were to encrypt at the column level (and example of doing this [Encrypt data in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508440/encrypt-data-in-sqlite/47518804#47518804) but in Java).

You could perhaps include a factor when encrypting that would change, probably not ultra-secure but incorporate the date/time stored in a column. So it could be pass phrase + date/time from the respective row to encrypt/decrypt. The same underlying data would then differ. Perhaps you could encrypt the actual data + a date/time, again the stored data would (should) differ. Of course doing this could possibly allow the data to be easier to hack as there could well be some data that is easily determinable.

There are likely other potential solutions, Virtual tables  may be one; see https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html